# How can I use flask-ngrok with flask-socketio?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio, ngrok

I tried to use:

```
socketio.run(app=app)
run_with_ngrok(app)
```

but that didn't work, is there any way to use flask-ngrok with socketio? I tried using pythonanywhere, but its very laggy.

Answer (score 0):

You could in theory do this...

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
run_with_ngrok(app)

@app.get('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

...except that `flask_ngrok` is buggy and unmaintained (last updated in 2019, and a slew of un-addressed issues in the github repository). The above code will fail because flash_ngrok sets incorrect permissions on a directory in `/tmp`.

I don't think that `flask_ngrok` is getting you anything: it doesn't integrate flask with ngrok in any meaningful fashion; it just starts ngrok automatically after starting your flask app.

You can do that yourself just by running `ngrok http 5000`.